# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key unitControl SegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, uisegmentedcontrol

I am trying to make a Segmented Control that can change between Metric and US units, but the app crashes with NSUnknownKeyException every time the class is accessed. I am tried many solutions here on SO, but none works. I checked my outlet lists, uninstall and reinstall my app on the simulator, clean the project but nothing work out.

This is my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SettingsController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *unitControl;

}

- (IBAction)unit:(id)sender;

@end
```

and my .m file:

```
#import "SettingsController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface SettingsController ()

@end

@implementation SettingsController

-(IBAction)unit:(id)sender{

    ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0){
        viewController.metric = YES;
    }

    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 1){
        viewController.metric = NO;
    }

    [viewController setUnits];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

I have tried commenting away all the code in unit:sender but the app still crashes with the same error. Also, when I remove the IBOutlet reference, the app crashes with another exception NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff04bf39510

[image: Screenshot of storyboard links]

Comment: I don't understand the code.  You create a view controller, set things up with it and then it gets destroyed?  That doesn't make *any* sense.

Comment: @Droppy destroy? What did I destroy?

Comment: OK, you need to understand about scoping.  When you create an object within a method and that method returns, what do you think ARC does with that object?

Comment: You mean ViewController *viewController? This line had nothing to do with the error. @Droppy

Comment: So why did you post it? You asked me what you'd destroyed and I told you.

Comment: How you created outlet for uisegmented control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These errors are common when there are missing connections, I just did a single view project, copy-pasted your code (you're missing @end at the end of implementation but I think you just forgot to paste it here) connected IBOutlets and IBActions (commented the inside of the unit code) and it worked flawlessy.

Comment: I have deleted the Segmented Control and reconnected everything again but It still won't work.

Comment: Maybe its something with that segue you have referenced in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

**Some times Xcode keeps cache of Storyboard and Xibs in DerivedData.**

- Clear DerivedData
- Restart your Xcode

[image]

- Select Your project and click on **Delete** button to remove DerviedData.